# Automate my task of creating a virtualenv and django

Tags: python, django, automation

Recently I tried to automate few of my tasks which I perform on daily basis.

The task are :

1. go to a specific folder
2. create a virtual environment in that folder
3. go inside the virtual environment folder and then activate the virtual environment
4. install django using pip command

I am using subprocess module in python and for now I am able to achieve till step 2

Here is the code :

py_sample.py

---

```
import os
import subprocess

cwd = os.getcwd()

change_dir = os.chdir(cwd)

# to create a virtual env
virtualenv = input('Enter the name of virtual env : ')

#run the python virtualenv command
p1 = subprocess.run('python -m virtualenv {}'.format(virtualenv),shell=True)


virtualenv = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), virtualenv)

#go inside the virtual env folder
os.chdir(virtualenv)

#activate the virtual environment
p2 = subprocess.run(r'.\Scripts\activate.bat',shell=True)
```

### cmd

```
C:\Users\swaru\Downloads>python py_sample.py
Enter the name of virtual env : django_env
created virtual environment CPython3.8.2.final.0-32 in 1423ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\swaru\Downloads\django_env, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\swaru\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.1.1, setuptools==49.2.1, wheel==0.34.2
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

C:\Users\swaru\Downloads>dir/b
django_env
```

You can see the virtualenv is created but I am unable to activate the virtualenv.
What I am missing here can anyone guide me how to proceed.

Comment: What do you do this for? Can you not just create a docker container to run?

Comment: I had no idea we use docker for this ? Will try that for sure

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, if you're trying to use an untainted django environment then yes

Comment: well i want to simply automate all the commands i run for starting a  django project using one python script.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the dot in subprocess command (before \Scripts):

insted of

```
p2 = subprocess.run(r'.\Scripts\activate.bat',shell=True)
```

it should be

```
p2 = subprocess.run(r'\Scripts\activate.bat',shell=True)
```

Comment: I got the error "The system cannot find the path specified." when did the above-mentioned change